# Docker-Compose Connection Refused with ASP-NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I've been using ASP.NET Core 5.0 for a project and running it via docker-compose inside VS2017 Community.
Previously when I ran the project it would connect to a port automatically published by Visual Studio and load the web application (see image 1). However, similarly to another project, it simply refuses connection when debugging starts (see image 2).

[image: Ports]
[image: Refused Connection]

Even when manually publishing the ports via the `ports:` portion of the `docker-compose.yml` file it still refuses connection.

After trying to find a solution to no avail, I've turned to asking here. I've tried all of the following:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Deleting the `.vs` folder and restarting.
- Restarting computer.
- Exposing ports `80` and `443` explicitly in `docker-compose.yml`
- Checking out to previous, known working commits.

As mentioned before this behavior has also started occurring on a university assignment which is running ASP.NET Core 3.1, which I prefer to have working before it's due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `Clean/Purge Data` on Docker Desktop for Windows, restarted and it seems to be working now. I really wish I knew what actually causes this problem so I can avoid in in the future....